# How to get "Subject" value from Gmail API response?

Tags: java, json, gmail-api, arrayobject

Below is the sample response I get from Gmail API payload headers. How do I get the "Subject" value from the below array of objects.

I do not want to use `response.get(index).getValue().toString();` as the index will change from message to message.

```
  [{
    "name": "From",
    "value": "Someone <someone@example.com>"
  },
  {
    "name": "To",
    "value": "xyz@example.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Subject",
    "value": "This is the subject value"
  }]
```

Comment: you will have to loop through array and find which has name as 'Subject'

Comment: Yep, that's a textbook solution. I am looking if there are any better ways to transform the DS and retrieve it.

Comment: If you look at the API reference they return a `List` with `To, From and Subject`. Note that, the index is not fixed (not mentioned in the API). So yes you only have the option of looping over

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using Streams?

Comment: what about https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp?

Comment: @sawim I am looking for a solution in Java.

Comment: Sorry, this json mislead me ;) but still there is a solution. If you want to use streams, filter with findFirst method should do what you want